# Jquery select menu for changing css style

Tags: jquery, css

I need to dynamically change the style with jQuery on a select menu. Here's what I have so far:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myText">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum bla bla bla...</p>
        </div> 

        <label for="myTextFontSize">Font-Size</label><br />
        <select id="myTextFontSize">
            <option label="8px" value="8px">8px</option>
            <option label="9px" value="9px">9px</option>
            <option  label="10px" value="10px">10px</option>
            <option selected="selected" label="14px">14px</option>
        </select>

        <script>
            $("select#myTextFontSize").change(function() {
                var str = "";
                $("select#myTextFontSize option:selected").each(function() {
                    str += $(this).val();
                });
                $("#myText p").css('font-size', str);
            }).trigger('change');            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on a working solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myTextFontSize').change(function() {
   $('#myText p').css('font-size', $(this).val()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried $("#myText p").css('font-size', str) ? I do not think text-size is a valid CSS attribute.